# Typesetting tree with groups of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest, trees

How can I create a tree in which some of nodes are in groups so there is no space in between them and only one arrow connects parent and whole group, but I can still add child nodes (of the same style) to these nodes in group individually? It's important that arrow must come out from one of the nodes, not the middle of group. I tried to do that using `rectangle split` but I couldn't find convenient way to add children. The final effect (more or less) I'm looking for:
[image: tree]

Perfect will be the solution where I can create simple `rectangle` nodes and then somehow group them and apply styles to make them look like on picture.

Comment: How important is it that this is a tree? (Even if formally it is one.) This would probably be simpler as a matrix of multipart nodes with arrows drawn between the parts.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned @Alan Munn in his comment, your three can be simpli draw as pure TikZ picture using `positioning` and `shapes.multipart` libraries:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 11mm,
every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb, very thick},
  MPNV/.style = {
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=10,
    rectangle split ignore empty parts,
    draw},
        ]
\node (n1)  [MPNV=1] {single node};
\node (n2)  [MPNV=3, right=of n1, anchor=three west]       
                                       {node 1 in group
                     \nodepart{two}     node 2 in group 
                     \nodepart{three}   node 3 in group};
\node (n3)  [MPNV=3, right=of n2]       {node 1 in another group
                     \nodepart{two}     node 2 in another group
                     \nodepart{three}   node 3 in another group};
\node (n4)  [MPNV=3, below=of n3]       {node 1 in another group
                     \nodepart{two}     node 2 in another group
                     \nodepart{three}   node 3 in another group};
\node (n5)  [MPNV=1, below right=of n2.east |- n4.south]       
                                       {another single node};
%
\path   (n1.east)       edge (n2.west)
        (n2.one east)   edge (n3.west)
        (n2.two east)   edge (n4.west)
        (n2.three east) edge (n5.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above MWE enables adding nodeparts to up to ten. If you like to have more nodeparts, than accordingly increase `rectangle split parts=...`. Not used (empty) nodes are not drawed. For drawing connection arrows, you need to use anchors of `nodepart`s.